# Unwind Segue and Mutl-Threading

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uiviewcontroller

A view controller is launched modally from a parent view controller and later unwinds to its parent if one of three buttons is pushed:

```
@IBAction func parentSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.tag {
    case 1:
        parentType = ParentStoryboardId.meetings
    case 2:
        parentType = ParentStoryboardId.accounts
    case 3:
        parentType = ParentStoryboardId.contacts
    default:
        parentType = ParentStoryboardId.accounts
    }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToNotes", sender: self)
}
```

The unwind segue handler in the parent VC then launches another Table VC with a list of entries:

```
@IBAction func unwindToNotes(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
     if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? SelectParentVC {
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let parentType = sourceViewController.parentType 
             else {
                return
             }
            self.parentSelected = parentType
            self.displayParents(parentType)
            self.selectParentView.isHidden = true
          }
     }
 }
```

Originally I didn't specify the main queue when performing all of the UI operations invoked by the unwind segue handler in the parent VC. And the list view I was trying to invoke didn't display, though debugging confirmed that the list VC was partially executing.

It seems like some of the UI operations invoked from unwind segue handler were relegated to a background thread. I'm trying to figure out how that happened since none of the operations leading up to the "unwind" operations were explicitly run on a background thread. Any insights or links would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue wasn't that you weren't running on the main queue.  Your problem was that you were trying to present a new view controller while one was in the process of being dismissed.

By using a `DispatchQueue.main.async` you are causing the presentation of the view controller to occur on the next iteration of the main runloop, after the previous view controller has been dismissed.

Comment: Thanks. That answer makes alot of sense. I got rid of the unwind segue and went back to using the dismiss method for other reasons. Interestingly, that eliminated the need for specifying the main thread for those operations. Any idea why a view controller dismissing itself as opposed to unwinding via a segue would eliminate the need for the main thread closure?